# Drawbacks using box-shadow instead of border

Tags: html, css

We can emulate simple borders with box-shadow: `box-shadow inset 0 0 0 1px black`. However, I was wondering if there are any drawbacks (performance, compatibility, ...) in using box-shadows instead of borders.

The reason I am asking is, that design applications don't take outside borders into account when measuring distances between elements - so most of the stuff is designed with inset borders. This is reflected in Invision (our design-development handoff tool of choice), so when using the exact values for margins/paddings this leads to differences between design and final implementation.

I found some hints online, that box-shadow had a performance impact when it was introduced years ago, but I'm not sure if that is still the case.

Comment: Look up `box-sizing: border-box;` - this box model includes border into width/height calculations

Comment: My gut feeling says that the performance hit is worse when using a blur radius, but I wouldn't know how much. Would have to test. Anyway, just use box-sizing:border-box and be done with it.

Comment: Just tested `box-sizing: border-box` with JS calculations. And JS does indeed take all CSS properties to account. But it could be that modern browsers have optimized `box-shadow` without blurs. Yet I don't see any advantage of `box-shadow` over `box-sizing` + `border`

Comment: While `box-sizing` will overcome measuring between elements, it still affect the inside of an element. A great alternative is to use a pseudo element for the border, which will have the same advantage `box-shadow` has, though most likely more performant.

Answer (score 2):

Since one of the drawbacks that you are looking for is compatibility, `box-shadow` is known to be incompatible with [most e-mail clients](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/) including Gmail.

So, if you ever design an e-mail that uses `box-shadow`, expect that CSS3 property to be stripped out of your e-mail by the email clients and the e-mail would be malformed then.

On the other hand, `border` is well supported everywhere, so you don't need to worry about how the e-mail would look like.